# ngx-facebook npm package's ui mathod promise is never resolving or rejecting

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am using ngx-facebook package to login and share into Facebook in my angular 6 project. Login is working fine but when i am going to share a post into Facebook, after successful share ui popup is not closing. I checked for issue and i got that callback in .then() or .catch() mathod is never calling. This is my code-

```
export class MyClass(){
  constructor(
     @Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window,
    private fb: FacebookService, 
 ) {
    const initParams: InitParams = {
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.10'
    };
    fb.init(initParams);
  }
  shareOnFb(options : any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const newOption: UIParams = {
        method: 'share',
        href: options.href,
        redirect_uri: 'https://myUrl.com/404#confirm'
      };
      this.fb.ui(newOption)
      .then((res: UIResponse) => {
        if (res.error_message) {
          this.toastrService.error('failed');
          reject();
        } else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      }).catch((e : any) => {
          reject();
      });
    }
}
}
```